# Portable haskell stack install on usb stick

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to make portable haskell development environment in my usb stick with msys2 and stack.

- Install msys2 on usb stick.
- `set STACK_ROOT=f:\stack` in msys2_shell.bat. # f is usb stick
- Copy `stack.exe` to msys2 `/usr/bin` directory.

I've changed `local-bin-path` config on `f:\stack\config.yaml`. And It looks like working.

However, `stack setup` command still install ghc on system directory somwhere like `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\i386-windows\ghc-7.10.3`.

How could I tell stack to install ghc on usb stick(cutom directory)?